# Akka HTTP. Streaming source from callback

Tags: scala, stream, akka-http

I am trying to connect Akka HTTP and some old Java library. That library has two methods - one accepting a callback function to receive string, and one signaling the end of data stream. The callback function receiving the data can be called multiple times. Consider this snippet:

```
   oldJavaLib.receiveData((s:String) => {
       println("received:" + s)
   })

   oldJavaLib.dataEnd(() => {
       println("data transmission is over")
   })
```

I want to stream data using Akka HTTP as its being received by the callback function. But I am not sure what is a best way to go about that.
I was thinking to create a stream and then use it directly in HTTP route like this:

```
  def fetchUsers(): Source[User, NotUsed] = Source.fromIterator(() => Iterator.fill(1000000) {
    val id = Random.nextInt()
    dummyUser(id.toString)
  })
  
  lazy val routes: Route =
      pathPrefix("test") {
        concat(
          pathEnd {
            concat(
              get {
                complete(fetchUsers())
              }
            )
          }
        )
      }
```

`fetchUsers()` function should return a stream which is getting data from some legacy java API. May-be there is a better approach.

Comment: You probably have to create a Akka stream wrapping your Java calls.

Comment: Yes, I just dont know how to do it, reading docs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that you want to create an Akka stream that emits values from callback? You can use [Source.queue](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/stream/operators/Source/queue.html). For the first callback it would be:

```
val queue = Source.queue[String](bufferSize = 1000)
                .toMat(Sink.ignore)(Keep.left)
                .run()
oldJavaLib.receiveData((s: String) => {
   queue.offer(s) match {
       case Enqueued => println("received:" + s)
       case _ => println("failed to enqueue:" + s)
   }
})
```

### Edit after question clarification

If you want to use the source in HTTP route you have to [prematerialize it](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/stream/stream-flows-and-basics.html#source-pre-materialization). Refering to my previous code it would look like this:

```
val (queue, source) = Source.queue[String](bufferSize = 1000).preMaterialize()
```

`source` then can be used in any route.

Comment: Thanks. How do I use this queue in the HTTP route?

Comment: Can you edit the question and give example how you want to use the results of callbacks? It will be easier to suit your needs.

Comment: I have edited it

Comment: I've edited my answer as well.